# support selecting of multiple favorite tags

Tags: feature-request, tag-watching, tag-search

I realize you can concat tags in the search bar like so: `[java] [multithreading] [pillowcases]`

However I notice when you click a favorite tag to filter by it, it hides the other favorite tags. Why not keep this in view, so you could quickly drill down using various combinations of tags, with only the mouse?

The functionality is already there with the search bar, the workflow is just missing for favorite tags.